# Create a REST API in spring integration using Spring tool suite

Tags: spring, rest, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

I need to create Restful APIs in Spring Integration.I found a example for the same in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/rest-http But somehow this example is not working for me. I was wondering if there is any way to create a Restful API in Spring Integration using STS. As STS provides graphs for Spring Integration, how can we create a REST API using STS graphs directly.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Of course you can. What is your exact problem?

Comment: I imported the Rest-http example in STS, ran Spring Tools->Update Maven dependencies and then Run As on Pivotal tc server. I am getting error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationEvaluationContext':... I want to create a sample REST API using Spring Integration similar to given in this example. I have less time for development, can I implement same example using STS quickly.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include this information. "...is not working for me..." is not a suitable question for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are having trouble with the sample, I just tested it and it worked ok.

However, probably the simplest way to get started with STS is (using a recent version >= 3.7)...

1. File | New... | Spring Starter Project
2. Set the name to, e.g. `rest`
3. Click next
4. Select `Web`, `Integration` (under IO)
5. Click Finish
6. Open `demo.RestApplication` (where `Rest` is capitalized name from #2)
7. Add `@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")`
8. Create `context.xml` in src/main/resources
9. Run the application and hit `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` in your browser - it will output `BAR`.

RestApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")
public class RestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

    <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="in"
            path="/foo/{id}"
            supported-methods="GET"
            request-payload-type="java.lang.String">
        <int-http:header name="requestedId" expression="#pathVariables.id" />
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <int:transformer input-channel="in" expression="headers['requestedId'].toUpperCase()" />

</beans>
```

**EDIT**

To make a deployable war, follow the [Spring Boot instructions 'Create a deployable war' here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

**But see the note about old servlet containers that don't support servlet 3.x.**

Here's the updated `RestApplication` class...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:context.xml")
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RestApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. This example worked for me from STS. If I need to deploy this as war file on JBOSS server then what steps should I follow. I did mvn clean and install. But I got "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/context.xml]" error.

Comment: Add `classpath:` to the `@ImportResource` and see the Spring Boot instructions on how to make a deployable war. I edited the answer with a link

Answer (score 1):

I discover something that might help you, try this link: https://dzilengine.wordpress.com/2015/08/02/seraphim/ it is a presetted Rest engine, hope it might help you